# how to pass div value to mysql query in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

how to pass div value to database in php mysql

say for example

im having

```
<div id='item'>50</div>
```

is there any possibility to pass the div value 50 into select query where condition

say for example

```
<php
    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id = 50"
?>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Comment: read about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  !

Comment: ... and [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: $('#tem').text() where i have to put this

Answer (score 1):

[joke] just prefix your username with **A** and tada! You get the answer! [/joke]

Javascript -

```
var reqText = document.getElementById('source_div').innerHTML;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'test.php?req='+reqText, true);
xhr.onload = function() {
    //do stuff
};
xhr.send(null);
```

test.php -

```
<?php
    $req = $_GET['req'];
    //use $req in your sql query.
?>
```